# How can I apply function to all new elements with the same class, but only for the newly created elements? (JS function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have a list of elements on the page and I want to run a function only on the newly created elements. The problem is when I call the function again it applies the function on *all* the elements with the same class.

```html
<ul>
    <li class="element">Created on load 1</li>
    <li class="element">Created on load 2</li>
    <li class="element">Created dynamicly 1</li>
    <li class="element">Created dynamicly 2</li>
</ul>
```

In the example code above I have list of elements with a class of `element`. I want to call a function that runs only on the elements created dynamically, ie. not those in the DOM when loading the page

Comment: What sort of function? What does it do, take in the element and do something with it?

Comment: Use a second class name on the dynamically created elements so you can tell the difference and hence only select the new ones. So `<li class="element dynamic">` or something.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the function is to change the text color to the new elements added

Comment: How and when are you appending the new elemnts?

Comment: @Shilly This is still problematic because the new elements also become old and then the function run on them again

Comment: @DanielC remove all the dynamic classes from all elements before inserting new dynamic elements, so they are only there on the last created ones.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The elements comes from the server by AJAX call

Comment: In which case you already have a reference to the new elements separately. You just need to call the function on them. Exactly how you do that depends on the code you've not yet shown us; the function you call and the AJAX request logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help, the most helpful solution I found to the problem is:- Every time i run the function I'm remove the orignal class name and add a new one, Now when the function runing is searches for a class name with the orignal name so it's end up that only the elements with the orignal name changes.

Here is the magic that change elements:

```
$('.element').removeClass('element').addClass('element-processed');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `MutationObserver` API for listening to the changes to the child list of an element. The following example demonstrates a possible usage. Most part was shamelessly copied from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) site.

```js
const targetNode = document.querySelector('ul');

const config = {
  attributes: false,
  childList: true,
  subtree: false
};

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
    }
  }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

///
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = 'dynamically added';
  li.classList.add('element');
  
  document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="element">Created on load 1</li>
  <li class="element">Created on load 2</li>
</ul>

<button>Add more elements</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of my comments.
You can add/remove another class at the correct times so the CSS will only color the items that were added in bulk last.

```js
const add_items = texts => {
  const previous_items = document.querySelectorAll( 'li.dynamic' );
  Array
    .from( previous_items )
    .forEach( item => item.classList.remove( 'dynamic' ));
  const new_items = texts.map( text => {
    const new_item = document.createElement( 'li' );
    new_item.textContent = text;
    new_item.classList.add( 'element', 'dynamic' );
    return new_item;
  });
  const list = document.querySelector( 'ul' );
  new_items.forEach( item => list.appendChild( item ));
};

document.querySelector( '#add_1' ).addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  add_items([ 'Created dynamically 3' ]);
});

document.querySelector( '#add_2' ).addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  add_items([
    'Created dynamically 4',
    'Created dynamically 5'
  ]);
});
```

```css
.element {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.dynamic {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="element">Created on load 1</li>
  <li class="element">Created on load 2</li>
  <li class="element dynamic">Created dynamicly 1</li>
  <li class="element dynamic">Created dynamicly 2</li>
</ul>
<button id="add_1">Add 1</button>
<button id="add_2">Add 2</button>
```